# pandas filter by multiple conditions without chaining

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I want to filter a pandas dataframe by multiple condiitons that have to hold together.

```
d = {'price': [1, 2, 0 ,0,1], 'description': ['a', 'a','b','c','e']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
li = ['a','b']
df = df[(df['price']!=0) & (~df['description'].isin(li))]
```

The problem is, that it removes all prices that are 0 and then removes everything thats in li.
I want it to remove rows in the dataframe that hold both conditions together and not only one of it.

expected output would be:

```
   price description
      1           a
      2           a
      0           c
      1           e
```

but instead it is:

```
   price description
      1           e
```

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: based on your description i think you may be looking for or-> `|` instead of and -> `&`

Comment: i can't use and because isin returns a series

Comment: @stackofacc - Super, can you add expected output?

Comment: I think you are confused in the use of masking. Masking does not *remove* but *extracts* the rows that follow your condition(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code **selects** all rows that meet the following criteria:

1. `df['price']!=0`: price different than zero

Returns:

```
0 True
1 True
2 False
3 False
4 True
```

2. `~df['description'].isin(li)`: description not in li

Returns:

```
0 False
1 False
2 False
3 True
4 True
```

The combination of these two boolean arrays leads to:

```
(df['price']!=0) & (~df['description'].isin(li))
>> 0    False
>> 1    False
>> 2    False
>> 3    False
>> 4     True
```

That is, only the last row of your dataframe (price = 1, description = e) meets both criteria.

From your description, you might want to use an "OR" operator, `|`:

```
(df['price']!=0) | (~df['description'].isin(li))
>> 0 True
>> 1 True
>> 2 False
>> 3 True
>> 4 True
```

Which will remove only the row with (price = 0, description = b).

Hope it helps!
Cheers,
T

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edited expected output,

Just replace the and `&` with an or `|`

```
df = df[(df['price']!=0) | (~df['description'].isin(li))]

#Output
price description
     1           a
     2           a
     0           c
     1           e
```

Comment: Okay that works, but it seems very confusing to me as it states either first or second condition has to hold. Instead it works the other way around.

Comment: Strange, where does it state that? Could you link it.
But in general,
AND & means 'both' the conditions must hold, 'together'.
OR | means 'atleast one' of the conditions must hold

Comment: Look at what you just wrote, and look at the solution: using  |  is the solution for making both of the conditions hold, and keeping stuff that is filtered by only one of the conditions